# Write JSON with Qt5

Tags: c++, json, qt

I've been stuck on this for a while, I'm trying to write JSON with this syntax

```
{
    "1": {
            "type": "spin",
            "timeTap": 2.000,
            "timeEnd": 9.600,
            "beatState": 1,
            "rotation": 12
        },

    "2": {
            "type": "tap",
            "timeTap": 10.800,
            "beatState": 2,
            "rotation": 15
        } }
```

but I've trouble understanding the way QJson works. I'm not looking for a full answer, rather a way to understand it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What seems to be the issue though? Or what is your specific question?

Comment: With Qt5, I'd recommend using the classes coming with Qt: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qjsondocument.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
QVariantMap object1;
object1["type"] = "spin";
object1["timeTap"] = 2.0;
object1["timeEnd"] = 9.6;
object1["beatState"] = 1;
object1["rotation"] = 12;

QVariantMap object2;
object2["type"] = "tap";
object2["timeTap"] = 10.8;
object2["beatState"] = 2;
object2["rotation"] = 15;

QVariantMap root;
root["1"] = object1;
root["2"] = object2;

qDebug() << QJsonDocument(QJsonObject::fromVariantMap(root)).toJson();
```

Note that `QJsonDocument::fromVariant(root)` seems to work too, but in its documentation `QVariant::Map` type is marked as obsolete, so I'm not sure it will work in future versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I've found the problem since then, that's the method I used !